# Deep merge two json object react

Tags: javascript

I have two json object in which one is nested. For example:

```
data1 : [{"name": "abc", "age": 26, "title": "xyz", "address": {"street":"yyy","city":"ttt","country":"kkk"}]
date2: [{"color": "blue", "sqad": "jkl", "priority": "rst", "division": "opq", "range": 456}]
```

I tried to merge them using spread operator and also object.assign but not getting the expected result.

I need it combined like below:

```
[{"name": "abc", "age": 26, "title": "xyz", "color": "blue", "sqad": "jkl", "priority": "rst", "division": "opq", "range": 456 }]
```

Comment: Object.merge()?

Comment: What have you tried ? post the code

Comment: How are you merging them using spread operator? And what result do you get on merging them using spread operator? Because this should be doable using  spread operator.

Comment: @Victor there's no Object.merge in vanila js, you meant Object.assign ?

Comment: what if you have more than one object in the arrays?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, sorry. I meant `Object.assign` indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This uses [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
    let data1 = [{"name": "abc", "age": 26, "title": "xyz" }];

    let data2= [{"color": "blue", "sqad": "jkl", "priority": "rst", "division": "opq", "range": 456}];  

    let mergedArray3 = [{...data1[0], ...data2[0]}];

    console.log(mergedArray3)
```

```js
    let data1 = [{"name": "abc", "age": 26, "title": "xyz" }];

    let data2= [{"color": "blue", "sqad": "jkl", "priority": "rst", "division": "opq", "range": 456}];  
    let mergedArray3 = [{...data1[0], ...data2[0]}];
    
    console.log(mergedArray3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 let data1 = [{"name": "abc", "age": 26, "title": "xyz" }];
 let data2= [{"color": "blue", "sqad": "jkl", "priority": "rst",
 "division": "opq", "range": 456}];  

 let newObj = Object.assign(data1[0], data2[0]);
```